# Difference between named location and last argument in try_files

Tags: nginx

I have got this code example:

```
events {}

http {

   include mime.types;

   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name 172.16.239.128;

      root /sites/demo;

      try_files $uri /cat.png /greet /friendly_404;

      location /friendly_404 {
         return 404 "Sorry, that file could not be found.";
      }

      location /greet {
         return 200 "Hello User";
      }
   }
}
```

And

```
http {

   include mime.types;

   server {
      listen 80;
      server_name 172.16.239.128;

      root /sites/demo;

      try_files $uri /cat.png /greet @friendly_404;

      location @friendly_404 {
         return 404 "Sorry, that file could not be found.";
      }

      location /greet {
         return 200 "Hello User";
      }
   }
}
```

In the first case we are using the last argument to do a try_files which is consider as a rewrite right? Which means we are gonna read the file over with a new uri `/friendly_404` in order to catch the location right?

In the second case, we are using named location, which acts like a `go to` in bash for example? Right?

So it is better to use the second case in order to don't re-load all the file?

I am not sure if what I have said is correct, after long hours looking over the net it is my conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `try_files ... /uri;`, if none of the *file* terms match, it performs an internal rewrite, which means that the value of `$uri` is changed and Nginx restarts the search for a `location` to process the request.

In the case of `try_files ... @name;`, if none of the *file* terms match, the named `location` is selected to process the request. The value of `$uri` remains unchanged.

In a simple test scenario, there may be little difference between the two.

> So it is better to use the second case in order to don't re-load all the file?

In both cases, these processes are internal to Nginx, and do not involve an external redirection. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.